# Eslint Component is defined but never used in Vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, eslint

In Vue3, I'm getting this kind of error:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import ProductItem from '@/components/ProductItem.vue';
</script>

<template lang="pug">
#ProductList.base-bg-color
  h2.mt2.pb0 Selected

  ProductItem.mb4(v-for="product of itemsInCart" :product="{...product, selected: true }" @changeSelected="changeSelected(product, $event)")
```

> 'ProductItem' is defined but never used

According to [this](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/script-setup-uses-vars.html) this problem should be fixed in vue-eslint-parser: 9, which I have.

I have also attempted to apply that rule (vue/script-setup-uses-vars) and still no luck.

My package.json:

```
...
 "devDependencies": {
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.3.3",
    "@tsconfig/node18": "^18.2.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.5.2",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^8.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^12.0.0",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.5.0",
    "eslint": "^8.49.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.17.0",
    "npm-run-all2": "^6.1.1",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "~5.3.0",
    "vite": "^5.0.10",
    "vue-pug-plugin": "^2.0.3",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.8.25"
  },
```

.eslintrc.cjs:

```
require('@rushstack/eslint-patch/modern-module-resolution');

module.exports = {
  root: true,
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    'plugin:vue/vue3-recommended',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/eslint-config-typescript',
    '@vue/eslint-config-prettier/skip-formatting',
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
  },
  rules: {
    'vue/script-setup-uses-vars': 'error', // doesn't seem to be working
  },
};
```

The version of vue-eslint-parser installed (by something) in `node_modules/vue-eslint-parser` is 9.3.2.

Any suggestions?